# Pass raw response to client from asyncmongo

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado

I'm working on javascript API for filtering items by querying mongodb. No server-side processing needed. I just query mongodb and send its response to browser to javascript deal with it. Is it possible to not parse mongodb response and pass it as string through tornado to client (browser) to avoid useless json serialize/deserialize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw MongoDB response is [BSON (Binary JSON)](http://bsonspec.org/) which still requires some massaging into JSON.  You can see examples of BSON types and encoded data on the [specification page](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification).

I'm not sure if there is a pure-JavaScript BSON parser available .. but in general serialization in lower level language such as C is much faster than using interpreted languages such as Python and JavaScript.  The PyMongo driver includes a C extension for BSON, which is recommended for performance.

Any server-side effort you might save in converting from BSON to JSON will be much more expensive to try to do via browser-based JavaScript.

Related reading:

- [PyMongo and Performance](http://wicknicks.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/pymongo-and-performance/) - blog post with comparison of PyMongo serialization with and without the BSON C extension (TL;DR: 145 seconds in pure Python vs 8 seconds with the C extension)
- [BSON Specification](http://bsonspec.org/)